# Presenting view controller with overCurrentContext then pushing to navigation stack results in navigation bar underlapping

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uimodalpresentationstyle

I'm hitting my head against the wall with a navBar issue.  See this [sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w35c6jgqo8b9dm4/Test.zip?dl=0) for a better idea of what I'm trying to achieve.  Basically, my app structure is like this:

```
NavController -root-> ViewControllerA -> button -> push -> ViewControllerB                            --> ViewControllerC
                                                              |                                      |
                                                            button -> presentModally                 |
                                                              |                                      |
                                                              V                                      |
                                                        PopoverViewController                        |
                                                              |                                      |
                                                            button -> push to the nav controller     |
                                                              |                                      |
                                                              |                                      |
                                                              ---------------------------------------
```

A button on the second view controller (call it B) of the nav stack will present a modal view controller with a clear background (its modal presentation style is `overCurrentContext` to look like a popover):

[image: ViewControllerB]

[image: Popover]

Then, a button on the popover will push a new view controller on to the nav stack (call it C):

[image: PresentingC]

[[image: ViewControllerC]

The popover is presented by B as opposed to the actual nav controller (B defines the presentation context).  This so that when the popover pushes C on the stack, C doesn't just cover B, but covers the popover as well.

The problem arises when dismissing C.  The nav stack pops back to B with the popover still on top (which is my intention).  However, B now fills the entire frame of the nav view controller (before C was pushed, B's top was pinned to the navBar).  This causes views near the top of B to be clipped  by the navBar:

[image]

A look at the UI Inspector confirms that this is because B's view now fills the nav controller's view:

[image]

This was not the case before C was presented.  Any ideas as to what's causing this to happen?

Comment: Solved by chance?

Answer (score 1):

You are manually pushing a view controller onto the stack which doesn't have a navigation controller. A better way to do it would be to segue from view controller B to view controller C using a segue identifier. Once you setup the segue in the storyboard you will see that view controller C gets a nav bar automatically. You might want to use a delegate method from the popover view controller to B to trigger the segue.

Comment: I tried that.  Made a `show` segue from B to C and used a delegate method from the popover's tap function to B to trigger the segue.  It still behaves the same way.  I also tried setting B's `definesPresentationContext` to `false`.  That solves C getting clipped, but it also causes the popover to be presented by the nav controller, on top of all further VC's pushed to the stack.  I tried tinkering with different `modalPresentationStyles` for the popover, but `overCurrentContext` seems to be the only one that satisfies my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem very similar to this one. I was presenting a view controller using a `.overCurrentContext` presentation mode. When the viewController was displayed the navigation was over it!

To solve the problem I just asked to the navigation show the new view controller instead of the old viewController.

```
viewController.navigationController?.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Doing by this way the viewController will not be behind the navigation anymore. I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

swift 5

I did this way:

```
let vc = viewControllerToDisplay()
let navVc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

navVc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
navVc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve

navigationController?.present(navVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```